# When is it Counterproductive to Separate PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

Understanding that it is less load on the server to not have to parse HTML, when does it work the other way, as far as server performance.

The majority of my Web sites are database-driven - often the same cosmetic structure with entirely different information. Separating the HTML, which is minimal compared to the PHP involved, does it come to a point where excessive calls to PHP defeat the performance gained by separating the two? I am totally aware of the possibility that I do not totally understand how PHP processing takes place. I am listing two examples below.

Unless I am misunderstanding how PHP works, in this little bit of code, I am making 5 calls to PHP, whereas the second is only one.

(Please excuse the old mysql. This was just a convenient example)_

Separate

```
<div class="Filters">
   <?PHP
   $Result = mysql_query( --- Complex query --- );
   if(!$Result){$Error[] = "Database Error! [4]";}
   else
   {
      $L = mysql_num_rows($Result);
      $CatItems[] = "All";
      while($C=mysql_fetch_array($Result))
      {
         $CatItems[] = $C['Cat'];
      }
      sort($CatItems);
      $a = $L%2 == 0 ? (int)($L/2) : (int)($L/2)+1;
      ?>
      <div class="2Col">
      <?PHP
      for($x = 0; $x < $a; $x++)
      {
         ?>
         <div class="FilterItem">
            <div class="CriteriaSelect" data-cat="<?PHP echo($CatItems[$x]);?>"><?PHP echo($CatItems[$x])?/>
            <div class="FilterCount">
               <?PHP  
               if($CatItems[$x] == "All"){$Rows = $ProgRows;}
               else
               {
                  $CCount = mysql_query( --- Complex query --- );
                  $Rows = mysql_num_rows($CCount);
               }
               echo('('.$Rows.');
               ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

PHP Writing HTML

```
<?PHP
echo('
<div class="Filters">');
   $Result = mysql_query( --- Complex query --- );
   if(!$Result){$Error[] = "Database Error! [4]";}
   else
   {
      $L = mysql_num_rows($Result);
      $CatItems[] = "All";
      while($C=mysql_fetch_array($Result))
      {
         $CatItems[] = $C['Cat'];
      }
      sort($CatItems);
      $a = $L%2 == 0 ? (int)($L/2) : (int)($L/2)+1;
      echo('
      <div class="2Col">');
      for($x = 0; $x < $a; $x++)
      {
         echo('
         <div class="FilterItem">
            <div class="CriteriaSelect" data-cat="'.$CatItems[$x].'">'.$CatItems[$x].'
            <div class="FilterCount">');
               if($CatItems[$x] == "All"){$Rows = $ProgRows;}
               else
               {
                  $CCount = mysql_query( --- Complex query --- );
                  $Rows = mysql_num_rows($CCount);
               }
               echo('('.$Rows.');
               echo('
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>');
   ?>
```

Comment: "Unless I am misunderstanding how PHP works [...]" I believe you are. You say you are "making calls to PHP" which does not make sense. You speak about "it is less load on the server to not have to parse HTML" but it is unclear what you mean exactly. If you are concerned about performance, you need to profile your application. If you are concerned about architecture, you should read about different patterns such as MVC, MVVM and so forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two examples are effectively equivalent – the PHP engine processes the *entire* file and interprets the outside HTML roughly as if it were a string that is printed out like in the second example. There is no extra overhead. And if there is any overhead, it is *insignificant* compared to actions like waiting for a database response, or negotiating an encrypted HTTPS connection.

The real answer though is “neither”. While PHP was originally developed to allow small PHP snippets to be inserted into an (otherwise normal) HTML file, this is now considered unmaintainable and even dangerous. For example, notice that you fail to perform HTML escaping of the output you are echoing. If someone can insert a string of their choice into the database, they could perform an XSS attack.

For these reasons, the current best practice is to use a separate *template engine* to render the HTML contents. Most template engines escape by default (so are secure-ish by default), and require you to opt out of escaping if you really have a variable that contains verbatim HTML. For example, the PHP Symfony web framework uses the [Twig template language](https://twig.symfony.com/).

Comment: Yes - I think the right way to think of it is that in PHP `?> foo <?php` is just an alternate syntax for `echo ' foo ';`

Answer (score 0):

## Separation of functionalities is almost always worthwhile.

If you have a big monolithic piece of code then it becomes completely unwieldy to maintain. Remember you don't just write code for yourself. You write it for the people who may read your code as well.

Separating it into small bite-size pieces of code makes the maintaining of the code base many times easier. It is also much easier to refactor and get in line with some external code standard.

If you have ever spent time trying to decipher what poorly written code does, you would realise the importance of having code only do one thing (As far as possible.) Even if there could be case made for the resulting code do slightly more server calls than what is necessary the upside is still very much worthwhile.